# Missing argument 1 for MyController in RESTful application

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, basic-authentication

I am developing app in laravel (REST server), using [Basic Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#http-basic-authentication). Using Postman, all GET requests I have implemented seem to work, but unfortunately POST requests not.

routes.php:

```
Route::post('my/action', 'MyController@postMyAction');
```

My Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.basic.once');
}

public function postMyAction($request)
{
    // some logic here
}
```

The problem is, that  this way, after setting credentials and some params in Postman, following exception appears:

> Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\MyController::postMyAction()

Does anybody knows how to put request into post-processing function defined in routes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides dependency injection for controller methods, however you need to typehint exactly what you want so Laravel knows what to inject:

```
public function postMyAction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) 
{
    // Now $request is available
```

Now Laravel knows you want an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` and it will give it to you.

Of course you can also stick `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your controller then just typehint `Request $request` as the argument.

Comment: It works, thanks. I didn't know that typehint is needed there.